# Enrolling IAS Zone devices

Tags: wireless-networking

I am using trying to add IAS zone devices (from HEIMAN) to my ZCL co-ordinator(CIE) (from NXP)

1. The emergency button gets added easily and triggers successfully

[image: IAS zone Emergency Button - pairing]

2. The door sensor joins the network but no enrolment process is seen

[image: IAS zone door sensor - pairing]

1. Why is it such that one device undergoes enrolment process correctly and the other doesn't? My understanding is that the ZCL stack should do all the enrolment activities. Am I correct?
2. I tried writing IEEE address of the CIE to the node's cluster(0x0500) attribute (0x0010) of attribute type (0xf0). But no response. How to tackle this issue?